# T-SQL: Compare 2 XML and return nodes with different values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have 2 xml variables (@xml1 & @xml2) and I need to compare the values in each node and return an xml that only contains the nodes that are different.

So say, I have these 2 XML variables:

```
declare @xml1 xml = N'<row>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>record title</name>
  <description>sample description</description>
</row>'
declare @xml2 xml = N'<row>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>record title</name>
  <description>updated sample description</description>
</row>'
```

I'd like it to return:

```
SELECT @xml1 = N'<row>
  <description>sample description</description>
</row>', @xml2 = N'<row>
  <description>updated sample description</description>
</row>'
```

I have the following query that returns sort of what I need, but its UNpivoted & doesn't have the xml nodes, etc.:

```
SELECT
        NV.NodeName,
        OV.NodeValue OldValue,
        NV.NodeValue NewValue
FROM 
(SELECT T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') NodeName,
                T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') NodeValue
            FROM @xml1.nodes('/row/*') T(N)) NV
CROSS APPLY (SELECT T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') NodeName,
                T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') NodeValue
            FROM @xml2.nodes('/row/*') T(N)) OV
WHERE OV.NodeName = NV.NodeName AND OV.NodeValue <> NV.NodeValue
```

PERFORMANCE IS KEY: This code is in a trigger, so it needs to run fast and I'm afraid of using PIVOT since it tends to be slow. I'm hoping there's a better way to compare and return the values already as an xml value.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind - figured it out =)
In case this helps anyone down the road:

DECLARE @XMLString1 VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @XMLString2 VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

```
SELECT @XMLString1 += '<' + OV.NodeName + '>' + LEFT(OV.NodeValue, 8000) + '</' + OV.NodeName + '>',
       @XMLString2 += '<' + NV.NodeName + '>' + LEFT(NV.NodeValue, 8000) + '</' + NV.NodeName + '>'
FROM 
    (SELECT T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(255)') NodeName,
            T.N.value('.', 'varchar(8000)') NodeValue
    FROM @xml1.nodes('/row/*') T(N)) NV
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(255)') NodeName,
            T.N.value('.', 'varchar(8000)') NodeValue
    FROM @xml2.nodes('/row/*') T(N)) OV
WHERE OV.NodeName = NV.NodeName AND OV.NodeValue <> NV.NodeValue
SET @XMLString1 = '<row>' + ISNULL(@XMLString1, '') + '</row>';
SET @XMLString2 = '<row>' + ISNULL(@XMLString2, '') + '</row>';

SELECT CONVERT(XML, @XMLString1) xml1, CONVERT(XML, @XMLString2) xml2
```